# a grammar error while installing "vision_opencv"

Tags: ros, catkin-make, vision-opencv, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i use catkin & wstool to install the package: vision_opencv.

but there is some errors while i use catkin_make command.i haven't changed anything in the vision_opencv file downloaded form github. this is the output in the Terminal.

```
/home/shuixiu/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/module.cpp: In function ‘boost::python::api::object cvtColor2Wrap(boost::python::api::object, const string&, const string&)’:
/home/shuixiu/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/module.cpp:329:12: error: invalid conversion from ‘long int*’ to ‘npy_intp* {aka int*}’ [-fpermissive]
/home/shuixiu/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/module.cpp:331:13: error: invalid conversion from ‘long int*’ to ‘npy_intp* {aka int*}’ [-fpermissive]
/home/shuixiu/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/module.cpp:333:13: error: invalid conversion from ‘long int*’ to ‘npy_intp* {aka int*}’ [-fpermissive]
/home/shuixiu/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/module.cpp:335:13: error: invalid conversion from ‘long int*’ to ‘npy_intp* {aka int*}’ [-fpermissive]
/home/shuixiu/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/module.cpp:337:13: error: invalid conversion from ‘long int*’ to ‘npy_intp* {aka int*}’ [-fpermissive]
/home/shuixiu/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/module.cpp:339:13: error: invalid conversion from ‘long int*’ to ‘npy_intp* {aka int*}’ [-fpermissive]
/home/shuixiu/catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/module.cpp:341:13: error: invalid conversion from ‘long int*’ to ‘npy_intp* {aka int*}’ [-fpermissive]
make[2]: *** [vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge_boost.dir/module.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge_boost.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/100161/a-grammar-error-while-installing-%22vision_opencv%22/) by [doudoushuixiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/8281/doudoushuixiu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-11-11

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I came across this error as well when trying to compile the vision_opencv package. The fix is on line 325 where it defines the 'dims' variable as a lont int.

```
long int dims[] = {mat.rows, mat.cols, mat.channels()};
```

Change that to an int so it reads

```
int dims[] = {mat.rows, mat.cols, mat.channels()};
```

and it should compile without issue.

---

Originally posted by [ccostes](https://answers.ros.org/users/8881/ccostes/) with karma: 26 on 2013-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) on 2013-11-22**:
Please report that kind of bug upstream if that happens. That is now fixed in vision_opencv 1.10.13. (Numpy 1.x has a different API between Ubuntu releases apparently)